# jQuery.getScript() fails to load function

Tags: jquery, function, undefined, getscript

I am trying to load a script with a function like:

```
$.getScript('/js/mymy.js').done(function(){ 
    if(readCookie('my_cookie', 'yes')){
        /* do sth here */
    }
});
```

or

```
$.getScript('/js/mymy.js',function(){   
    if(readCookie('my_cookie', 'yes')){
        /* do sth here */
    }
});
```

where "readCookie" is defined in mymy.js but i get an error "readCookie" is not defined...

Here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716310/not-defined-function-from-getscript) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026191/can-i-use-jquery-getscript-without-a-callback) is where i have got help how to do, but it does not work... Any Ideas?

i do use jQuery 1.8.0

mymy.js does contain a function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

  /** There is sth much more here **/
  ...
  /** There is sth much more here **/
});
```

Comment: can you post the contents of mymy.js?

Comment: added definition of readCookie

Comment: thanks, and that function is not within another function right?

Comment: It is standonly function in jQuery(document).ready(function() { }};

Comment: that's your problem, it's within that document ready function scope. Take it out of there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readCookie` is undefined because `readCookie` is not global; it is visible only within the `document.ready` function scope in `mymy.js`.

Make the function global by removing the `document.ready` wrapper.

Comment: It might be good to also mention that it might not have been executed, too.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

> The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.

In other words, you cannot rely on the `success` function to be called explicitly after the loaded script is *executed*, e.g., its functions put into the global scope.

---

After your edit (which IMO should have been what you posted first) you actually have *two* issues; as written it's scoped *only* inside JQ's DOM-ready function.)

Comment: Interestingly, that text now says "The callback is fired once the script has been loaded and executed."